# Using 'prepositional phrase' at the end

Tags: prepositional-phrases, style

Can we omit "at that contract" at the end of the following sentence?

> I was signed to a contract at Disney for $75 a week but lasted only 18
>   months [at that contract].

Comment: "...but lasted" suggests that you could no longer stomach working there.  "...but *it* lasted..." on the other hand means the contract term was 18 months.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you for the clarification. I was thinking about the phrase (at that contract). Can I omit it or not?

Comment: If you leave it off or don't leave it off, your sentence suggests that you were signed to a contract by Disney but terminated the contract early, possibly in breach of its terms.  Leaving it off does not change the meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much @TRomano. I got what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

The second phrase does not have a subject, so you would expect it to be the same as in the first phrase, "I". So:

> I was signed to a contract at Disney for $75 a week but **I** lasted only 18 months.

But it could also mean:

> I was signed to a contract at Disney for $75 a week but **it** lasted only 18 months.

Here *it* means the contract, which is the meaning you intended with *[at that contract]*.

But because the subject in each phrase is different, it is better to have a subject in both phrases to avoid confusion.